# Method to pass argument to select Yes and No radio button

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, awt

I am trying to pass method argument to select "Yes" radio button or "No" radio button.

**MY CODE**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Demo();
  }
  public Demo() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              JFrame frame = new JFrame();
              frame.add(new TestPane());
              frame.pack();
              frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
              frame.setVisible(true);
          }
      });
  }
  public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    private static final int NUMBER_CHECK_BOX = 10;
    JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[NUMBER_CHECK_BOX];
    JRadioButton yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
    JRadioButton no = new JRadioButton("No");
      private Set<String> selectedValues = new HashSet<>(8);
   //   JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING));
      public TestPane() {
          setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
          setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
          JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
          JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING));
          yes.setSelected(true);
          yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  if (yes.isSelected()) {
                      textField.setEnabled(true);
                      toggleCheckBoxesEnabled(false);
                      //panelCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                  }
              }
          });
          no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  if (no.isSelected()) {
                    textField.setText("");
                      textField.setEnabled(false);
                      toggleCheckBoxesEnabled(true);
                  }
              }
          });
          ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
          bg.add(yes);
          bg.add(no);
          JPanel enterClassPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
          enterClassPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enetr Your MetaClass", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
          enterClassPane.add(yes);
          enterClassPane.add(no);
          for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_CHECK_BOX; i++) {
              checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox("Diagram " + i);
              checkBoxList[i].setEnabled(false);
              panelCheckBox.add(checkBoxList[i]);
              checkBoxList[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      System.out.println("Selected Diagram " + e.getActionCommand());
                      if (e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) {
                          JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                          if (cb.isSelected()) {
                              selectedValues.add(cb.getActionCommand());
                          } else {
                              selectedValues.remove(cb.getActionCommand());
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
          JPanel classPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
          classPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Meta Class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
          classPane.add(textField);
          JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
          JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
          btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  System.exit(1);
              }
          });
          JButton btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
          btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  //Text field
                  System.out.println(textField.getText());

                  for (String command : selectedValues) {
                      System.out.println(command);
                  }
              }
          });
          actionsPane.add(btnOkay);
          actionsPane.add(btnCancel);

          GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
          gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
          gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
          gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

          add(enterClassPane, gbc);
          add(new JScrollPane(panelCheckBox), gbc);
          add(classPane, gbc);
          add(actionsPane, gbc);
      }
        
      private void toggleCheckBoxesEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        for (JCheckBox box : checkBoxList) {
            box.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
    }
  }
  public void methodName(String parameterName){ 
    if (parameterName.equals("yes")) {
        buttonyes.setSelected(true);
    } 
    else if(parameterName.equals("no")){ 
        buttonNo.setSelected(true);
    }
    else{
        buttonYes.setSelected(false);
        buttonNo.setSelected(false);
    }
}
  public class WrapLayout extends FlowLayout {
      private Dimension preferredLayoutSize;
     public WrapLayout() {
          super();
      }
      public WrapLayout(int align) {
          super(align);
      }
      public WrapLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap) {
          super(align, hgap, vgap);
      }
      @Override
      public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
          return layoutSize(target, true);
      }
      @Override
      public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
          Dimension minimum = layoutSize(target, false);
          minimum.width -= (getHgap() + 1);
          return minimum;
      }
      private Dimension layoutSize(Container target, boolean preferred) {
          synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
              int targetWidth = target.getSize().width;
              Container container = target;
              while (container.getSize().width == 0 && container.getParent() != null) {
                  container = container.getParent();
              }
              targetWidth = container.getSize().width;

              if (targetWidth == 0) {
                  targetWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
              }
              int hgap = getHgap();
              int vgap = getVgap();
              Insets insets = target.getInsets();
              int horizontalInsetsAndGap = insets.left + insets.right + (hgap * 2);
              int maxWidth = targetWidth - horizontalInsetsAndGap;
              //  Fit components into the allowed width
              Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
              int rowWidth = 0;
              int rowHeight = 0;
              int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();
              for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++) {
                  Component m = target.getComponent(i);
                  if (m.isVisible()) {
                      Dimension d = preferred ? m.getPreferredSize() : m.getMinimumSize();
                      //  Can't add the component to current row. Start a new row.
                      if (rowWidth + d.width > maxWidth) {
                          addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);
                          rowWidth = 0;
                          rowHeight = 0;
                      }
                      //  Add a horizontal gap for all components after the first
                      if (rowWidth != 0) {
                          rowWidth += hgap;
                      }

                      rowWidth += d.width;
                      rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, d.height);
                  }
              }

              addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);

              dim.width += horizontalInsetsAndGap;
              dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap * 2;

              Container scrollPane = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, target);

              if (scrollPane != null && target.isValid()) {
                  dim.width -= (hgap + 1);
              }

              return dim;
          }
      }

      private void addRow(Dimension dim, int rowWidth, int rowHeight) {
          dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, rowWidth);

          if (dim.height > 0) {
              dim.height += getVgap();
          }

          dim.height += rowHeight;
      }
  }
}
```

In Default Yes Radio button is selected.

I want to pass argument in method with "Yes" or "No",

- If I pass Yes in method the Yes Radio button should be selected and run.
- If I pass "No" radio Button No radio button should be selected and executed.

Comment: What problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a method or want to add it to one of your methods you should give a string parameter you can set "Yes or No". Then you can add the following Code to your method.

```
public void methodName(String parameterName){ 

    if (parameterName.equals("Yes")) {
        buttonYes.setSelected(true);
    } 
    else if(parameterName.equals("No")){ 
        buttonNo.setSelected(true);
    }
    else{
        buttonYes.setSelected(false);
        buttonNo.setSelected(false);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have access to that object. You created your Radio-buttons in the constructor, so its getting lost after methodperform by garbage collector. The parameterName stands for your parameter String. buttonYes and buttonNo are the names for the Yes and No Radio-Button. The else is for wrong parameter. You can change that default case how you want. In this case if you tipp in a Wrong Answer like "maybe" no Radio-Button gets selected. I would highly recommand to declare Radio Buttons and Button-Group as attributes outside the Constructor

Short Solution:

```java
 import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Demo();
}
public Demo() {
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame();
           frame.add(new TestPane());
           frame.pack();
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           frame.setVisible(true);
       }
   });
}
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
 private static final int NUMBER_CHECK_BOX = 10;
 JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[NUMBER_CHECK_BOX];
 JRadioButton yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
 JRadioButton no = new JRadioButton("No");
 ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
   private Set<String> selectedValues = new HashSet<>(8);
//   JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING));

   //You can change Method Name and Parameter Name
   public void methodName(String parameterName){ 

       if (parameterName.equals("Yes")) {
           yes.setSelected(true);
       } 
       else if(parameterName.equals("No")){ 
           no.setSelected(true);
       }
       else{
           yes.setSelected(false);
           no.setSelected(false);
       }
   }

   public TestPane() {
       setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
       setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
       JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
       JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING));
       yes.setSelected(true);
       yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (yes.isSelected()) {
                   textField.setEnabled(true);
                   toggleCheckBoxesEnabled(false);
                   //panelCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
               }
           }
       });
       no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (no.isSelected()) {
                 textField.setText("");
                   textField.setEnabled(false);
                   toggleCheckBoxesEnabled(true);
               }
           }
       });
       bg.add(yes);
       bg.add(no);
       JPanel enterClassPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
       enterClassPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enetr Your MetaClass", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
       enterClassPane.add(yes);
       enterClassPane.add(no);
       for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_CHECK_BOX; i++) {
           checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox("Diagram " + i);
           checkBoxList[i].setEnabled(false);
           panelCheckBox.add(checkBoxList[i]);
           checkBoxList[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   System.out.println("Selected Diagram " + e.getActionCommand());
                   if (e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) {
                       JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                       if (cb.isSelected()) {
                           selectedValues.add(cb.getActionCommand());
                       } else {
                           selectedValues.remove(cb.getActionCommand());
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
       }
       JPanel classPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
       classPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Meta Class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
       classPane.add(textField);
       JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
       JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
       btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.exit(1);
           }
       });
       JButton btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
       btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               //Text field
               System.out.println(textField.getText());

               for (String command : selectedValues) {
                   System.out.println(command);
               }
           }
       });
       actionsPane.add(btnOkay);
       actionsPane.add(btnCancel);

       GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
       gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
       gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
       gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

       add(enterClassPane, gbc);
       add(new JScrollPane(panelCheckBox), gbc);
       add(classPane, gbc);
       add(actionsPane, gbc);
   }
     
   private void toggleCheckBoxesEnabled(boolean enabled) {
     for (JCheckBox box : checkBoxList) {
         box.setEnabled(enabled);
     }
 }
}
public void methodName(String parameterName){ 
 if (parameterName.equals("yes")) {
     buttonyes.setSelected(true);
 } 
 else if(parameterName.equals("no")){ 
     buttonNo.setSelected(true);
 }
 else{
     buttonYes.setSelected(false);
     buttonNo.setSelected(false);
 }
}
public class WrapLayout extends FlowLayout {
   private Dimension preferredLayoutSize;
  public WrapLayout() {
       super();
   }
   public WrapLayout(int align) {
       super(align);
   }
   public WrapLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap) {
       super(align, hgap, vgap);
   }
   @Override
   public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
       return layoutSize(target, true);
   }
   @Override
   public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
       Dimension minimum = layoutSize(target, false);
       minimum.width -= (getHgap() + 1);
       return minimum;
   }
   private Dimension layoutSize(Container target, boolean preferred) {
       synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
           int targetWidth = target.getSize().width;
           Container container = target;
           while (container.getSize().width == 0 && container.getParent() != null) {
               container = container.getParent();
           }
           targetWidth = container.getSize().width;

           if (targetWidth == 0) {
               targetWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
           }
           int hgap = getHgap();
           int vgap = getVgap();
           Insets insets = target.getInsets();
           int horizontalInsetsAndGap = insets.left + insets.right + (hgap * 2);
           int maxWidth = targetWidth - horizontalInsetsAndGap;
           //  Fit components into the allowed width
           Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
           int rowWidth = 0;
           int rowHeight = 0;
           int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();
           for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++) {
               Component m = target.getComponent(i);
               if (m.isVisible()) {
                   Dimension d = preferred ? m.getPreferredSize() : m.getMinimumSize();
                   //  Can't add the component to current row. Start a new row.
                   if (rowWidth + d.width > maxWidth) {
                       addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);
                       rowWidth = 0;
                       rowHeight = 0;
                   }
                   //  Add a horizontal gap for all components after the first
                   if (rowWidth != 0) {
                       rowWidth += hgap;
                   }

                   rowWidth += d.width;
                   rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, d.height);
               }
           }

           addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);

           dim.width += horizontalInsetsAndGap;
           dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap * 2;

           Container scrollPane = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, target);

           if (scrollPane != null && target.isValid()) {
               dim.width -= (hgap + 1);
           }

           return dim;
       }
   }

   private void addRow(Dimension dim, int rowWidth, int rowHeight) {
       dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, rowWidth);

       if (dim.height > 0) {
           dim.height += getVgap();
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with code but I don't know where to add this. please can you help me with this.

Comment: If you really want to do this you should enter the parameter in the constructor like this `String parameterName` . Then you can add the code after you put your Radio-Buttons in the Button-Group. So after this code: `ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
          bg.add(yes);
          bg.add(no);`

Comment: I'm sorry, i added the code below the button group but i don't know whereto add the parameterName, I want this as a seperate method. in that method i want to pass this parameter. If i pass "Yes" Yes radio button want to select and if i pass "No", No radiobutton want to select

Comment: I just edited my answer. The method will only work if you have access to the objects. Therefore you need to put them as attributes. So You need to declare all stuff like `JRadioButton yes = new JRadioButton("yes");` outside of your constructor right under `JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[NUMBER_CHECK_BOX];`

Comment: Hello Mr. Gotta Gaming, I edited my code you can see in question, still i don't know where to apply this, can you help me with this? it will be so greatful to me.

Comment: I dont know if the code works itself. I just change the things you asked for. Its given under the Short Solution: in my original answer